# How do i resample a time-based dataframe with a CustomBusinessHour rule?

Tags: python, dataframe

i have a time-based dataframe, which i want to resample into three splits.

First Split from 4:00 to 12:00.
Second Split from 12:00 to 20:00.
Third Split from 20:00 to 4:00.

i've read about using the function CustomBusinessHour but it's not working well.

```
cbh = CustomBusinessHour(8, start='4:00')

Input: pd.date_range('20200309', periods=20, freq=cbh)

Output: DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-09 04:00:00', '2020-03-09 12:00:00',
           '2020-03-10 07:00:00', '2020-03-10 15:00:00',
           '2020-03-11 10:00:00', '2020-03-12 05:00:00',
           '2020-03-12 13:00:00', '2020-03-13 08:00:00',
           '2020-03-13 16:00:00', '2020-03-16 11:00:00',
           '2020-03-17 06:00:00', '2020-03-17 14:00:00',
           '2020-03-18 09:00:00', '2020-03-19 04:00:00',
           '2020-03-19 12:00:00', '2020-03-20 07:00:00',
           '2020-03-20 15:00:00', '2020-03-23 10:00:00',
           '2020-03-24 05:00:00', '2020-03-24 13:00:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='8CBH')
```

As you can see, the rule is not doing, what i want, which is probably caused by the "business hour", which i think ends at 16:00.

So i tried input another parameter "end=4:00". This throws an error, that i cannot input any endtime which would overlap with the starttime.

I am using Python 3.7 and Pandas 0.25.3

Answer (score 0):

Simply offsetting the Timestemp with following code does the work:

```
proxy = temp.index - pd.DateOffset(hours=4)
temp.index = proxy
resampled = temp.day_of_year.resample('8H').count()

# Adding Offset to retrieve original timestamp
resampled_df.index += pd.DateOffset(hours=4)
```

temp is the dataframe with DateTimeIndex. With the offset of 4 hours, every day would start at 4:00. '8H'-rule splits the day into three pieces afterwards.

If somebody has a better answer, feel free to answer.